# How do I make an search bar at the top of the page like on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I need to make the search bar at the top of the page like stackoverflow.com have in its website. I need some sample code for jsp/servlet for performing the operation for searching.
What operation it provide while one write something at the search bar. I want to search anything but into my website only.

Please give me some idea...

Thanks

Comment: And what is any special about search tool bar on this web site?
Actually here is the code for it:
<form id="search" action="/search" method="get">
                    <div>
                        <input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="search">

                    </div>
                    </form>

Comment: I do not see any reason for negating it... he specifically says "Please give me some idea"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/), that's a pretty good full text search engine. Since you are coding in Java it shouldn't be difficult at all to implement your search feature from Lucene.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use Google site search, there is more info [here](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/).

Or if you are willing to do more work you could check out the Apache Lucene project [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/).